# Is it appropriate to contract text names in a possibly informal sense in an English literature essay?

Tags: contractions, australian-english

I am writing a an essay comparing *The Great Gatsby* and *Pride and Prejudice* in English (Australian English style), and to save on word count I wondered if it would be appropriate to refer to them, after the first few uses of the names, as *Pride* and *Gatsby* respectively. Is this acceptable to do in a relatively formal context, and if so, is there any procedure for first introducing the contracted names?

Comment: Another option is abbreviations like GG, PAP. But check your style guide if you've been assigned one, or ask your teacher, as conventions vary.

Answer (score 3):

It certainly has been done. I remember in [Oxford's introductory text for Hume's An Enquiry concerning Human Understanding](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/an-enquiry-concerning-human-understanding-9780199549900?cc=au&lang=en&), the essay in question (*An Enquiry concerning Human Understanding*), after its first mention, was referenced simply as *Enquiry*.

Though, with your particular texts, there could be some issue. For *The Great Gatsby*, simply *Gatsby* could be easily confused with the character. And for *Pride and Prejudice* to be just *Pride* may put some false emphasis on that word (rather than the Prejudice). And, they're each just three words, which really isn't so long to warrant obvious contraction.

For me, I'd probably keep the original titles full, but you could consider brevity by other methods, for example:

- Mentioning the authors (e.g. *Fitzgerald's text* and *Austen's text*) or simply using the author's name to reference the text's intent (e.g. *Fitzgerald introduces the character of...* or *Austen foreshadows...*).
- Flagging discussion of a particular text using character's names, locations, or established landmark scenes.
- Sectioning certain discussions such that the texts could be referenced just as *the text/novel/narrative/etc*.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You could also use initials *PP* and *GG*. *Sir Gawain and the Green Knight* is frequently referred to as *SGGK*.  But in the body of the essay, you could say "the novel", when to do so wouldn't be ambiguous.